# Excel VBA: How to create VBA results onto a new page

Tags: excel, vba

Would appreciate any help here based on a previous question.

The code below was the original ask and finding a way in VBA to turn the original table into the output excel.

```
    Data    4/1/2012    4/2/2012    4/3/2012    4/4/2012    4/5/2012
V        10 20  30  40  50
H   5   10  15  20  25
S   6   12  18  24  30
R   8   16  24  32  40
A   9   18  27  36  45

Output : Excel Table
V        4/1/2012    10
V        4/2/2012    20
V        4/3/2012    30
V        4/4/2012    40
V        4/5/2012    50
H        4/1/2012    5
H        4/2/2012    10
H        4/3/2012    15
H        4/4/2012    20
H        4/5/2012    25
.
.
.
A        4/1/2012    9
A        4/2/2012    18
A        4/3/2012    27
A        4/4/2012    36
A        4/5/2012    45
```

The answer is below and works, but I was hoping for some help in terms of adapting the code below so the output is created on a new sheet within the same workbook. What code should be added? Thank you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub colsToRows()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim a As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long
Dim va As Variant, vd As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

        '-- set e.g. sheet name Sheet1, starting column = B, dates starting cell = C2
        Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = ws1.Range("B" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = ws1.Cells(Range("C2").Row, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

        '--put dates into this array as it repeats for each item
        vd = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws1.Range("C2").Resize(1, LastCol - 1)))

        '-- titles
        ws1.Range("B2").Offset(LastRow + 1) = "Item"
        ws1.Range("C2").Offset(LastRow + 1) = "Dates"
        ws1.Range("D2").Offset(LastRow + 1) = "Data"

        '--2 is deducted as the main range is starting from B3. So B3-B1 = 2
        For a = 1 To LastRow - 2
           '--to get next last row
            lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            '--items
            va = Array(ws1.Range("B2").Offset(a).Value)
            ws1.Range("B1").Offset(lr).Resize(LastCol - 1) = Application.Transpose(va)

            '--dates
            ws1.Range("C1").Offset(lr).Resize(UBound(vd)) = Application.Transpose(vd)

            '--data
            va = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws1.Range("C2").Offset(a).Resize(1, LastCol - 1)))
            ws1.Range("D1").Offset(lr).Resize(UBound(va)) = Application.Transpose(va)
        Next a

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will put the result on a new sheet.

Note, it assumes the data starts in A1 on Sheet1.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub colsToRowsToNewSheet()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim arrOut As Variant
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim idxCol As Long
Dim cnt As Long

        '-- set e.g. sheet name Sheet1, starting column = B, dates starting cell = C2
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Set ws1 = ActiveSheet

    arrData = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ReDim arrOut(1 To (UBound(arrData, 1) - 1) * (UBound(arrData, 2) - 1), 1 To 3)
    
    For idxRow = LBound(arrData, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)
        For idxCol = LBound(arrData, 2) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
            cnt = cnt + 1
            arrOut(cnt, 1) = arrData(idxRow, 1)
            arrOut(cnt, 2) = arrData(1, idxCol)
            arrOut(cnt, 3) = arrData(idxRow, idxCol)
        Next idxCol
    Next idxRow
    
    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
    
    wsNew.Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("Data", "Date", "Item")
    
    wsNew.Range("A2:C2").Resize(cnt).Value = arrOut
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you norie, do I just add that to the end of the original?

Comment: It replaces the original code. Note, it also assumes the original data starts in A1 on Sheet1.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but is there a way to make this apply to an active sheet instead of sheet1? Thank you.

Comment: All you need to do is replace `Sheets("Sheet1")` with `ActiveSheet` at the start of the code.